# Firebase Admin SDK 5.0.0, setCredentials cannot resolve method **Java**

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is running over a Servlet Module using Android Studio 2.3.2

```
private FirebaseApp app = null; // To avoid NullPointerExeception
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // the error points here: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("table/ID"); //Table from Firebase
```

---

This is inside the Get Method and I want to read just a value (Keep it simple).
My problem is on setCredential it just say that "cannot resolve the method"

I got in  the backend gradle file:

```
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.53'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.0.0'
```

---

I tried several different ways to implement the credentials, as you can see they are **"//commented"**.

Just one is working Admin SDK 4+ "setServiceAccount" **nowdays deprecated**, if I compile and deploy it to App Engine and then Firebase want to read the table it says: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.**

---

So I got two options here (**I am open to hear everything from you**):

1. setCredentials doesn't work
2. setServiceAccount compiles but doesn't work

   ```
   InputStream serviceAccount = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/YourJsonFile.json"); //JsonFile from Account Services 
   FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
       .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount)) // example (doesn't compile)
     //.setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.applicationDefault()) //same problem (doesn't compile)
     //.setServiceAccount(serviceAccount)                    //compiling & it throws the error: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
       .setDatabaseUrl("https://YourDatabaseName.firebaseio.com")
       .build();
   this.app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
   ```

And I am calling **myRef** to read the value like this:

```
     myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

**When I run the application, it point me to the line of FirebaseDatabase.getInstance** (on the attributes)

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer? Same problem here

Comment: Yes, I have solved my problem. When I came from work I'll post

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan. I did a workaround, so basically a String Text of the service account inside of the backend module servlet class, then I just add an InputStream that reads from the first String Text and then add the firebase options.. then the firebase init.. then the database ref... so those were my steps, if that were your question... about steps... but if you want the code maybe it will be a little messy. Just let me know if this works for you. can I ask you for some points? I need some.

Comment: I also face the same problem here. can you post your code?